# Translation of Dietrich von Hildebrand's “Die Bedeutung von Mann und Frau füreinander ausserhalb der Ehe”?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, sexuality, women, celibacy

Is there an online edition or English translation of:

- Hildebrand, Dietrich von. “Die Bedeutung von Mann und Frau füreinander ausserhalb der Ehe.” In *[Zeitliches Im Lichte Des Ewigen](https://books.google.com/books?id=RTQ3AAAAMAAJ)*, 143–44. Regensburg, 1932.

?

It was cited in [*Pastoral Psychology in Practice* by Willibald Demal, OSB, ch. 8 "The Psychology of Celibacy"](https://www.cathinfo.com/catholic-living-in-the-modern-world/the-psychology-of-celibacy/msg892887/#msg892887).